Image in SwiftUI takes extra space at bottom while trying to set Aspect Ratio
I want to have Image occupying full width of its container and height will be based on aspect ratio provided explicitly. Also the image should cover all its frame and doesn't matter its content is cut i.e. Aspect Fill mode as per following image.
Desired output: Aspect Fill


Way 1

Here is my View:
struct AspectImage: View {
    var heightMultiplier: CGFloat
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            Image(.leapord)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.width * heightMultiplier)
                .clipped()
                .border(color: .black, width: 5, radius: 22)
        }
    }
}

How I am using:
struct ImageAspectContainerView: View {
    var body: some View {
          VStack {
            Text("Hi")
            AspectImage(heightMultiplier: 0.3)
                .background(.gray)
            Text("Hello")
        }
    }
}

How it looks:

The image aspect ratio is working as expected but the image is taking space at bottom (gray area in the screenshot).

Way 2

I have tried .aspectRatio modifier but it does not give desired output:
struct AspectImage: View {
    var aspectRatio: CGFloat
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            Image(.leapord)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: proxy.size.width)
                .aspectRatio(aspectRatio, contentMode: .fill)
                .border(color: .black, width: 5, radius: 22)
        }
    }
}

struct ImageAspectContainerView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hi")
            AspectImage(aspectRatio: 2/1) // Aspect ratio 2:1
                .background(.gray)
            Text("Hello")
        }
    }
}


How it looks:

As you can see from the screenshot, the aspect ratio is not working. I first set the width to full available space and then setting aspect ratio using aspectRatio but it does not work.

Solution 1

I have tried solution provided by Benzy Neez, it's almost what I want to do but the only issue is image is streching:
struct AspectImage: View {
    
    let aspectRatio: CGFloat = 16/5
    
    var body: some View {
        ViewThatFits(in: .horizontal) {
            let theImage = Image(.leapord)
            theImage
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(aspectRatio, contentMode: .fill) 
            theImage
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(aspectRatio, contentMode: .fit)
        }
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 22))
        .overlay {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 22)
                .stroke(.black, lineWidth: 5)
        }
    }
}

struct AspectImageContainer: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hi")
            AspectImage()
                .padding(.horizontal)
            Text("Hello")
        }
    }
}

How it looks:


In your example, you are using .scaledToFill() for both your approaches. If you are trying to stretch the image by using a different aspect ratio to its natural aspect ratio, try using .aspectRatio(aspectRatio, contentMode: .fill) instead of .scaledToFill().
However, it is the GeometryReader that is consuming all of the space available and causing the gray background to fill the screen.
A GeometryReader can be avoided by using ViewThatFits to choose between scaled-to-fill and scaled-to-fit, depending on the aspect ratio:

when the image has an aspect ratio that is taller than the bounding container, it is scaled to fill
otherwise, when it has an aspect ratio that is wider than the bounding container, it is scaled to fit.

ViewThatFits(in: .horizontal) {
    let theImage = Image(.leapord)
    theImage
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
    theImage
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
}
.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 22))
.overlay {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 22)
        .stroke(.black, lineWidth: 5)
}

Again, if you want to apply a custom aspect ratio, then replace .scaledToFill() with .aspectRatio(aspectRatio, contentMode: .fill) and replace .scaledToFit() with .aspectRatio(aspectRatio, contentMode: .fit).
The approach above will fill the full width, with the height being determined by the aspect ratio of the image (or by the parameter to the .aspectRatio modifier, as applicable).
If you want to impose a maximum height, above which the image is clipped, then this needs to be applied before clipping and before the border is applied. Here is how AspectImage could be adapted to work like this:
struct AspectImage: View {
    let image: Image
    var maxHeight: CGFloat?

    var body: some View {
        ViewThatFits(in: .horizontal) {
            image
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
            image
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: maxHeight)
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 22))
        .overlay {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 22)
                .stroke(.black, lineWidth: 5)
        }
    }
}

Example use:
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Hi")
        AspectImage(image: Image(.image1), maxHeight: 350)
            .padding(.horizontal)
        Text("Hello")
    }
}


See also my answer to Image is being rendered with 1/3 of screen width for a way of scaling an image to fill the available width and fit within the available height. It might be that you are after the solution Maximum width, minimum height, which is the third part of the answer.

Thanks for the detailed answer, upvoted!
If I use aspectRatio, then image is stretching.
If I use maxHeight, then frame doesn't increase after certain number.

@NSPratik Yes, and yes. That would be the expected behavior. So if you don't want stretching, don't use .aspectRatio, and if you don't want clipping, don't set a maxHeight.

I have updated my question with the solution I have applied

Answer accepted as it fulfil my purpose
